# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 16 out of bounds for length 10 Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, indexoutofboundsexception, spring-mybatis

I encountered the following error during the posting paging process. I don't even use an array, but I don't know why I get this error. How can I solve this?

BoardCriteria is an object that stores the information needed to page the bulletin list.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 16 out of bounds for length 10

**controller**

```
// http://localhost:8088/club/{club_no}/boards
// http://localhost:8088/club/1/boards
@RequestMapping(value = "/{club_no}/boards", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String boardListAllGet(@PathVariable("club_no") Integer club_no, Model model, BoardCriteria cri) {
    log.info("club_no : "+club_no);
    
    
    List<BoardTotalBean> boardList = service.getBoardListAll(club_no, cri);
    log.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@"+boardList.get(16)+"");
    
    
    model.addAttribute("club_no", club_no);
    
    model.addAttribute("boardList", service.getBoardListAll(club_no, cri));

    
    //BoardPageMaker pageMarker = new BoardPageMaker();
    //pageMarker.setCri(cri);
    //pageMarker.setTotalCount(service.getTotalBoardCnt());
    //log.info(pageMarker+"");
    //model.addAttribute("pm", pageMarker);
    
    
    return "/club/boards/boardList";
        
}
```

**mapper.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE mapper
      PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
      "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
    
    <mapper namespace="com.joinus.mapper.ClubMapper">
    

    <resultMap type="MembersVo" id="membersMap">
       <id property="member_no" column="member_no"/>
       <id property="member_email" column="member_email"/>
       <id property="member_pass" column="member_pass"/>
       <id property="member_name" column="member_name"/>
       <id property="member_location" column="member_location"/>
       <id property="member_tel" column="member_tel"/>
       <id property="member_image" column="member_image"/>
       <id property="member_regdate" column="member_regdate"/>
       <id property="member_updatedate" column="member_updatedate"/>
       <id property="member_authority" column="member_authority"/>
       <id property="member_signup_type" column="member_signup_type"/>
       <id property="member_status" column="member_status"/>
       <id property="member_role" column="member_role"/>
       <id property="member_type" column="member_type"/>
       <id property="member_location" column="member_location"/>
    </resultMap>
    
    
    <resultMap type="ClubBoardsVo" id="clubBoardsMap">
        <id property="club_board_no" column="club_board_no"/>
        <id property="club_no" column="club_no"/>
        <id property="board_type_no" column="board_type_no"/>
        <id property="member_no" column="member_no"/>
        <id property="club_board_title" column="club_board_title"/>
        <id property="club_board_content" column="club_board_content"/>
        <id property="club_board_image" column="club_board_image"/>
        <id property="club_board_date" column="club_board_date"/>
        <id property="club_board_updatedate" column="club_board_updatedate"/>
        <id property="club_board_likecnt" column="club_board_likecnt"/>
        <id property="club_board_commentcnt" column="club_board_commentcnt"/>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap type="BoardTotalBean" id="boardListMap">
        <collection property="membersVo" resultMap="membersMap"/>
        <collection property="clubBoardsVo" resultMap="clubBoardsMap" />
    </resultMap>

    
        <select id="getBoardListAll" resultMap="boardListMap">
            <![CDATA[
            select b.club_board_no, m.member_name, m.member_image, b.club_board_title, b.club_board_content, b.club_board_image, b.club_board_date, b.club_board_updatedate, b.club_board_likecnt, b.club_board_commentcnt
            from club_boards b
            join members m
                on (b.member_no = m.member_no)
            where b.club_no = #{club_no}
            order by club_board_no desc
            limit #{pageStart}, #{perPageNum}
            ]]>
        </select>
        
        <select id="totalBoardCnt" resultType="java.lang.Integer">
            select count(club_board_no) from club_boards
        </select>
        
        
    </mapper>
```

**DAOImpl**

```
 package com.joinus.persistence;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    import com.joinus.domain.BoardCommentsVo;
    import com.joinus.domain.BoardCriteria;
    import com.joinus.domain.BoardLikesVo;
    import com.joinus.domain.BoardTotalBean;
    import com.joinus.domain.ClubBoardsVo;
    import com.joinus.domain.ClubMembersVo;
    import com.joinus.domain.ClubTotalBean;
    import com.joinus.domain.ClubsVo;
    import com.joinus.domain.Criteria;
    import com.joinus.domain.MembersVo;
    
    @Repository
    public class ClubDaoImpl implements ClubDao{
        
        @Inject
        private SqlSession sqlSession;
        
        static final String NAMESPACE ="com.joinus.mapper.ClubMapper";

    public List<BoardTotalBean> getBoardListAll(Integer club_no, BoardCriteria cri) {
        log.info("@@@@@@"+club_no+", "+cri);
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        param.put("club_no", club_no);
        param.put("pageStart", cri.getPageStart());
        param.put("perPageNum", cri.getPerPageNum());
        
        return sqlSession.selectList(NAMESPACE+".getBoardListAll", param);
    }
    }
```

**BoardCriteria**

```
package com.joinus.domain;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class BoardCriteria {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BoardCriteria.class);
    
    private int page;
    private int perPageNum;
    
    public BoardCriteria() {
        this.page = 1;
        this.perPageNum = 10;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        if(page <= 0) {
            this.page = 1;
            return;
        }
        
        this.page = page;
    }
    
    public void setPerPageNum(int perPageNum) {
        if(perPageNum <=0 || perPageNum > 100) {
            this.perPageNum = 10;
            return;
        }
        
        this.perPageNum = perPageNum;
    }
    
    
    public int getPageStart() {
        return (this.page - 1) * perPageNum;
    }
    
    
    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public int getPerPageNum() {
        return perPageNum;
    }
    
    // alt shift s + s
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BoardCriteria [page=" + page + ", perPageNum=" + perPageNum + "]";
    }
    
    

    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a limit of 10 in BoardCriteria:

```
public BoardCriteria() {
    this.page = 1;
    this.perPageNum = 10;
}
```

This might pose a problem when you attempt to access item 16:

```
List<BoardTotalBean> boardList = service.getBoardListAll(club_no, cri);
log.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@"+boardList.get(16)+"");
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't erase the code I used last time. My vision was so narrow. Thank you so much~!!